# Get selected text when clicking a button/link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to retrieve the selection **in a textarea** when I click of a button/link.

```
$(el).on('click', function() {
    console.log(window.getSelection().toString())
})
```

I got this, but it returns nothing. And I think the problem is because when I click on the button, the selection will dissapear. So of course is returns nothing then.

How would I fix this? Is there any way that I can click on the button and the selection will stay the same?

Comment: Huh, works for me http://jsfiddle.net/hyt4qc4u/

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention the text is in a textarea.

Comment: Replace `window.getSelection().toString()` with `$(this).html();` - [**Here's a jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bwahpLLo/)

Comment: Then I get all the html in the textarea. I want the selected html/text in the textarea.